# Using ArcMap to find borehole location to drill bore to fetch underground water?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, borehole

I have got an raster img file. I have the corresponding KML file. I wanted to find underground water using these two files. I wanted to know the steps to identify the location of water.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  What is shown in your IMG and in your KML files?  In what way do you expect to find underground water from this data?  What have you already tried.  Please **[edit]** your question to include more information about your data, what you have tried, and what you expect to get.

Comment: ArcGIS for Boreholes?